# Can't link to image with HTML on Rails app

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, image

I'm developing a Web app using Ruby on Rails. I have an image to add to the site, and I tried using the "img src" HTML tag to call a local image, but it won't work. If I use ruby to call it using the "image-tag" method, it works fine. I'm just wondering as to why it never works with HTML.

For example, I add an image to app>assets>images>image1.png

On the View file, I add HMTL as follows:

```
 <img src="/app/assets/images/image1.png">
```

It doesn't load

Yet if I enter this code in the same spot:

```
<%= image-tag: "image1.png" %>
```

It works fine.

Does anyone know why this is happening? I know I have a workaround, but I would rather know why my HTML tag has an issue with local files, yet links to files on the internet just fine. 
I'm new to coding.
Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice question. The Rails asset compiler is important but makes some problems like this one.

The asset compiler is likely adding a cache fingerprint to the file name. You can use `<%=asset_path('images/image1.png')%>` as the value of the `src` attribute, or continue using `image_tag`.

See [the Rails guide assets document](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/asset_pipeline.html) for more information.

Does that help?

Comment: Hello, 
Thanks for the answer. I tried <img src="<%=asset_path('images/image1.png')%>"> 
But it gave me an error saying the Asset couldn't be found

So then I tried <img src="<%=asset_path('/image1.png')%>"> 
Which didn't give me any errors but the picture still won't load, it's just displayed as a broken link.

When I inspect the image_tag (that works) it shows the HTML as follows:
img src= "/assets/image1-48e6870c46f97f301cb1d7c6e8fdf2d04c03dc407bf5f2199f27ad41f3f26137.png

Why is it adding all of this other information? This must be why I can't call it.

Comment: The extra information is a cache fingerprint, so that browsers can cache the resource and not reload it from the network. When the file changes, the fingerprint changes. Then browsers have to load the changed file. It's possible that I should have written `<%=asset_path('image1.png')%>`

Comment: <%=asset_path('image1.png')%> works fine, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you want use **img** tag you should:

```
<img src="<%= asset_path('image1.png') %>"/>
```

Without "/images" and "/".

Answer (score 0):

can you try with a online based example ? My guess is ruby isn't finding your image within the directory.

```
<img src ="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/32/Googleplex_HQ_%28cropped%29.jpg/250px-Googleplex_HQ_%28cropped%29.jpg"> </img>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your syntax is incorrect for the `image_tag` helper. Try this:

`<%= image_tag "image1.png" %>`

[More info in the Rails docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag)

Comment: Yep I wrote the tag incorrectly on here but I wrote it correctly on my app, the image tag is the one that works, its the img-src that doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the path you're using. Here's the short version: Remove `app/` from the image URL, and it should work as expected.

If you run the app with the working code, you can see that this is what `image_tag` is already doing for you behind the scenes by inspecting the HTML. You should see something like this:

```
<img src="/assets/images/image1.png">
```

Updating your `img` tag to use that path should resolve the issue.

However, you *should* be using `image_tag` if possible! Without delving too deep into the technical details, if you deploy your site to production with the `image_tag` version and take a look at the HTML, you'll probably see something like this:

```
<img src="/assets/images/image1-[sequence of characters].png">
```

This will help ensure that clients are removing stale assets from their caches as necessary - the technical details can be found [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) (see section 1.2). If you hard-code the image, you're going to miss out on any features provided by the asset pipeline.

Comment: I've tried omitting 'app' from the path and just entering in img src="/assets/images/image1.png", but that didn't work either. 

 
When I inspect the image_tag (that works) it shows the HTML as follows:
img src= "/assets/image1-48e6870c46f97f301cb1d7c6e8fdf2d04c03dc407bf5f2199f27ad41f3f26137.png

Why is it adding all of this other information? This must be why I can't call it. 

Cheers for the info about using image_tag instead!

Comment: That's covered by the documentation I linked - that's a fingerprint that's being generated by `image_tag`. If you make any updates to that image (or swap it out entirely), that string will change - meaning any browsers that have already cached the original image will be forced to request the new one.